# SharePoint Workflow Not Updating Date Field

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I have a workflow to check for the selection of a dropdown, and then take whatever I have placed in a start date field and, depending on the drop down selection, add a x number of days to the end date.

```
If CurrentItem:Selection equals Selection1
Add 2 Days to CurrentItem:Start Date (Output to Variable: date3)
then Set End Date to Variable: date3

Else if CurrentItem:Selection equals Selection2
Add 4 Days to CurrentItem:Start Date (Output to Variable: date4)
then Set End Date to Variable: date4
```

I save this. Upload it. I get no errors, but it doesn't work. I select a start date, and nothing happens to the end date field.

I'm very new to SharePoint all together, so I'm thinking I'm missing something simple, I just couldn't find an answer elsewhere.

I'm using SharePoint Designer 2010.

Comment: Workflow looks fine. Did you run the workflow manually after creating the item. There should be a column with the workflow name which tells you the status of the workflow if it is completed/cancelled or errored. Please check in there to see if there is any error mentioned.

Comment: Well, I don't know what happened. But I logged in to look at it today. That column was there, and it is working perfectly. Thank you very much for your help, Harini.